# How to optimize matching daterange table for dates with no records?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

Consider the following tables:

```
tweets                        daterange
---------------------------   ----------------
tweet_id  nyse_date   class   _date
---------------------------   ----------------
 1        2011-03-12  2       2011-03-11
 2        2011-03-12  1       2011-03-12
 3        2011-03-12  1       2011-03-13
 4        2011-03-12  1       2011-03-14
 5        2011-03-12  0       2011-03-15
 7        2011-03-13  1
 8        2011-03-13  2
 9        2011-03-13  3
10        2011-03-14  3
```

Each tweet has assigned a 'class', which is either 1, 2 or 3. I need an overview of the number of tweets of each class for each day within datarange. So even though there are no tweets on `2011-03-11` and `2011-03-15`, I still need that date to be included in the resultset, as follows:

```
nyse_date   total  class1  class2  class3
-----------------------------------------
2011-03-11  0      0       0       0
2011-03-12  5      3       1       0
2011-03-13  3      1       1       1     
2011-03-14  1      0       0       1
2011-03-15  0      0       0       0
```

I tried the following query, but it just times out (which it shouldn't because the database isn't that big):

```
SELECT
  t.nyse_date,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.nyse_date = d._date THEN 1 END) total, 
  SUM(t.class=1) as neu,
  SUM(t.class=2) as pos,
  SUM(t.class=3) as neg
FROM tweets t
CROSS JOIN
  daterange d
GROUP BY t.nyse_date
ORDER BY t.nyse_date ASC
```

Here's the `EXPLAIN`

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key  key_len ref    rows    Extra
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  SIMPLE      d     ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL   148     Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE      t     ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL   560783  Using join buffer
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a more efficient way to make sure all dates from the daterange table are included?

`edit`: I also tried this query, but the result stays the same - it runs untill it times out.

```
SELECT 
  t.nyse_date,
  COUNT(t.tweet_id) AS total, 
  SUM(t.class=1) AS neu,
  SUM(t.class=2) AS pos,
  SUM(t.class=3) AS neg
FROM tweets t
LEFT JOIN
  daterange d
  ON t.nyse_date = d._date
GROUP BY t.nyse_date
ORDER BY t.nyse_date ASC
```

Here's the `EXPLAIN`

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key  key_len ref  rows    Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  SIMPLE      t     ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL 560783  Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE      d     ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL 148
```

Comment: What is your indexing structure like? Try posting the `EXPLAIN` output of your query.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - please see the editted OP for the `EXPLAIN` output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your query is running slow is because it's not utilizing any indexes on your `tweets` table.

What you're going to want to do is create a composite index on the `(sp100_id, nyse_date)` columns in your `tweets` table, then run this query:

```
SELECT     
    a.sp100_id,
    b._date,
    COALESCE(c.total,0) AS total,
    COALESCE(c.neu,0) AS neu,
    COALESCE(c.pos,0) AS pos,
    COALESCE(c.neg,0) AS neg,
    COALESCE(c.spamneu,0) AS spamneu
FROM
    sp100 a
CROSS JOIN 
    daterange b
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        sp100_id,
        nyse_date, 
        COUNT(1) AS total,
        COUNT(CASE class WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) AS neu,
        COUNT(CASE class WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS pos,
        COUNT(CASE class WHEN 3 THEN 1 END) AS neg,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN class = 1 AND type = 1 THEN 1 END) AS spamneu
    FROM tweets 
    GROUP BY sp100_id, nyse_date
) c ON 
    a.sp100_id = c.sp100_id AND b._date = c.nyse_date
ORDER BY 
    a.sp100_id, b._date
```

---

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e94fa/3/0)

Comment: Here the same comment as under shawnt00. Oddly enough, it does return 2011-03-11 (with NULL values instead of 0 but that's OK) but it ommits 2011-03-15?

Comment: @Pr0no That's odd. It works perfectly on [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41145/1/0) using your sample data. What are the data types of your date columns?

Comment: I see it, and I wish I would know where the difference is with my database here. I've checked datatypes and they're all the same. Oddly enough, a `CROSS JOIN` does work: `SELECT d._date, COUNT(CASE WHEN t.nyse_date = d._date THEN 1 END) total FROM tweets t CROSS JOIN daterange d GROUP BY d._date ORDER BY d._date ASC` Any idea what that means?

Comment: (becasue I can't edit my previous comment anymore) Data types of date columns are both `DATE`...

Comment: @Pr0no, try my second solution and see if that gives you expected results. In that, I'm actually wrapping the grouping within it's own subselect so that the join makes the comparison on already grouped results. (It's probably faster as well.)

Comment: thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I think perhaps I have not made myself clear so please have a look at this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2eecc/5 I have put the desired output in the query field. In reality, I have tweets which all have one of the SP100 stocks as their subject. The subject is quantified by sp100_id. I need a list of every stock (in SQLFiddle there's only two stocks (sp100_id 1 and 2) given), for every _date in daterange.

Comment: P.S. I'm only able to come close to the desired output using `CROSS JOIN`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2eecc/15

Comment: @Pr0no, OHH!! Okay, now I see what your problem is now. There is an easy solution for this... but first I just need to know if there are unique sp100_ids stored in another table (like `sp100`).

Comment: you guessed right - `sp100.sp100_id` contains unique sp100_id's, see the updated http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0009/1

Comment: @Pr0no, you'll also probably want a composite index on the `sp100_id` and `nyse_date` fields in the `tweets` table for optimial speed.

Comment: thanks a bunch, man. It works great. Just a final question, please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e94fa/1 In tweets.type it says who posted each tweet (0 = human, 1 = spam, 2 = bot). I want to (see the updated desired output) count the number of spam tweets that are neutral. Originally, I used `SUM(t.type=1 AND t.class=1) AS spamneu` and it worked but I don't know how to incorporate this into your query. Your input, please?

Comment: @Pr0no, I simply added another `CASE` aggregation in the subselect. See [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e94fa/3/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e94fa/3/0)

Comment: This is great thanks. I need to expand the query to extract all info I need from my database but I think this is all the input I need. However, I ask you if you would have a peek at this thread tomorrow in case I would need your help? Also, since I can't attach a bounty to this question yet, I'm upvoting all your comments for the karma ;-)

Comment: @Pr0no, thank you very much =). I assume the optimization issue is solved, and so you shouldn't keep extending the question as if were your own help thread. Instead, I will be happy to help you with any further questions via email `->` zane{at}zanimation{dot}com.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were close. But you probably want the dates on the left side.

```
SELECT 
    d.nyse_date,
    COUNT(t.tweet_id) AS total, 
    SUM(t.class=1) AS neu,
    SUM(t.class=2) AS pos,
    SUM(t.class=3) AS neg
FROM daterange d LEFT OUTER JOIN tweets t t.nyse_date = d._date
GROUP BY d.nyse_date
ORDER BY d.nyse_date ASC
```

There's no need to jump to conclusions about indexes. Just try the query the right way before assuming too much.

**EDIT**

When I first wrote this I did not realize your tables used different names for the dat ecolumns. I wrote the query with an invalid column -- there is no d.nyse_date. If you had changed that to t.nyse_date or just dropped the qualifying alias instead of changing it to the correct column reference, d._date, then I think that explains the issue we saw with the data not coming back with the 15th included because it would be grouping on values from the inner table.

This is the version that ought to work:

```
SELECT 
    d._date,
    COUNT(t.tweet_id) AS total, 
    SUM(t.class=1) AS neu,
    SUM(t.class=2) AS pos,
    SUM(t.class=3) AS neg
FROM daterange d LEFT OUTER JOIN tweets t t.nyse_date = d._date
GROUP BY d._date
ORDER BY d._date ASC
```

Comment: Oddly enough, it does return `2011-03-11` (with `NULL` values instead of `0` but that's OK) but it ommits `2011-03-15`?

Comment: I don't see how the missing row would be possible and it's definitely worth double-checking the dates table. `COUNT()` generally returns zeros rather than nulls, but maybe I don't know something about mysql. A `COALESCE(COUNT(...), 0)` would definitely force that away.

Comment: @shawnt00, while `COUNT()` *does* count `NULL` values as `0`'s, `SUM()` will return `NULL` instead of `0` if it's passed all `NULL` values.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. So along with the missing row, we're seeing something that's a little weird and there's obviously a missing piece of the story. I actually suspect he was using SUM instead of COUNT when he reported that, but I hate to assume.

Comment: Obviously, something is missing here but I am unable to tell you what.  Oddly enough, a `CROSS JOIN` does work: `SELECT d._date, COUNT(CASE WHEN t.nyse_date = d._date THEN 1 END) total FROM tweets t CROSS JOIN daterange d GROUP BY d._date ORDER BY d._date ASC` Any idea what's up with that?

Comment: Maybe there's a timezone issue translating dates?

Comment: @shawnt00 Impossible; the two tables are on the same server, in the same database and of the same (`DATE`) type...

Comment: I figured that was unlikely. Is it worth dropping/re-creating indexes?

Comment: Try adding 2011-03-16 to the end of your date range.

Comment: @shawnt00 Just to be sure we're talking about the same I've created this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2eecc/5 In the queryfield I have put the desired output. In reality, all tweets also have a sp100_id (an `INT` referring to the S&P100 stock the tweet is talking about). I need a list for every sp100_id (in the SQLFiddle there's only sp100_id 1 and 2), for every _date in daterange. Again, see the desired output in the queryfield. BTW I really appreciate your help. I'm a business administration student trying to get his thesis round up, but SQL is withholding me :-)

Comment: P.S. I'm only able to get close to the desired output using `CROSS JOIN`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2eecc/15 Any comments?